# Ошибка при копировании с сохранением атрибутов по NFS

Tags: linux, shell, файловая-система, nfs, rsnapshot

NFS сервер на Debian Stretch раздает точки монтирования в локальную сеть c едиными настройками экспорта:

```
/path/to/nfs/share  hostname(no_root_sqash,rw,sync,crossmnt)
```

Клиенты, Debian Jessie/Wheezy монтируют с настройками по умолчанию

```
hostname:/path/to/nfs/share /mnt/dir nfs dfaults 0 0
```

Организована простая модель бэкап для клиентов, запускающая по крону скрип `rsnapshot` который, в свою очередь использует `cp -al` для создания очередного "слепка" дня/недели/месяца"

Проблема

В некоторых случаях `cp -al` выдает ошибку `Invalid arguments`, пробовал заменить опции на `cp -Rdl` работает без проблем, но игнорируется привилегии на файлы.

Стоит ли искать дальше причину проблемы или простое игнорирование привилегий будет оптимальным для резервных копий? Думаю это частичная проблема NFS но пока не смог ее "раскусить"

```
-a, --archive
              same as -dR --preserve=all
-d     same as --no-dereference --preserve=links
-R, -r, --recursive
              copy directories recursively
--preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
              preserve the  specified  attributes  (default:  mode,ownership,timestamps),  if  possible  additional
              attributes: context, links, xattr, all
-l, --link
              hard link files instead of copying
```

Comment: А разве nfs научился расширенные атрибуты понимать? Посмотрите на ваши файлы с помощью *lsattr*.

Comment: @0andriy Да-да именно, ищу способ как обойти жестко-закодированную опцию `rsnapshot`  `cp -al` .  Меня устроит  `cp -Rdl`, только странно , что на некоторых серверах проходит бекап без ошибок... мистика